# Generate dynamic input with python script

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2

I'm using 10.2.2 ArcGIS, I want to create a python script and have the following script:

I'm new to this topic
as I can use sys.argv [] or GetParameterAsText?
for can I make dynamic input coordinates and the name of the output shapefile

```
arcpy.env.workspace = 'C:\Users\Modelo IDEAL\Puntos.gdb'
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference('WGS 1984')
arcpy.env.outputCoordinateSystem = sr
latitude = 14.024982
longitude = -89.962368
p = arcpy.Point(longitude, latitude)
pg = arcpy.PointGeometry(p)
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(pg, 'salida.shp')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your [script into a tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00150000002q000000), and set it up to accept parameters. This will function like any other tool in the toolbox. It's a more detailed process than can be put here, but the link should get you started.

You could also just request coordinates and file name via raw_input, but I can see that being very error prone.

Answer (score 0):

If your coordinate data is stored in a table, shp, or feature class you can read in your coordinate data using a [Search Cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000011000000) and use a 'for' loop.  Which would look something like this:

```
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(file_With_Coord_Data_Here,["name","lat","long"]):
for row in cursor:
    latitude = row[1]
    longitude = row[2]
    p = arcpy.Point(longitude, latitude)
    pg = arcpy.PointGeometry(p, sr)
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(pg, row[0] + '.shp')
```

Depending on where exactly you wanted the output saved, you would need to supply a full file path name:

```
outFile = os.path.join(r'C:\temp', row[0] + '.shp')
```

or equivalent.